# How to create sub key in windows Registry Using Python winreg module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, window, registry, winreg

I want to add subkey in windows registry using python winreg. See the below picture for better understanding.

[image]

Now, I'm using this code.

```
import winreg as rg
regkey = rg.OpenKey(rg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, "Directory\shell", 0,rg.KEY_WRITE)
rg.SetValueEx(regkey, "IFO/dr",0,rg.REG_SZ, r"F:\IFO\dist\rename_folder.exe")
```

I just want to create the subkey and than want to add value.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new sub_key, you need to use `winreg.CreateKeyEx(key, sub_key, 0, access=KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY)`, where `key` is the root HKEY_ (E.g. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE), and `sub_key` is the fullpath key you want to create.

```
import winreg
    
rootPath = r"Directory\shell"
keyPath = r"IFO\dr"

# Open/Create the sub_key
winreg.CreateKeyEx(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, rootPath, 0, winreg.KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY)
# Set its value
winreg.SetValue(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, rootPath+'\\'+keyPath, winreg.REG_SZ,
                r"F:\IFO\dist\rename_folder.txt")
```